# How to setup delete selected messages feature in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I'm about to finish the final part of my thread messaging system for users. All deletion works great however before I move on to my next feature I'd like to give users the ability to delete selected messages.

Here's a way I've thought of doing it so far.

1. Add a check box tag to the each loop that loops through each message.
2. Have a "delete selected" link that goes to my messages controller "destroy_selected_messages" action.

What I need to do is some how grab an array of all the selected messages id's. Then pass it to the path as an argument. The delete all links path.

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Selected', messages_destroy_selected_messages_path(ARRAY_WITH_IDS), :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" if @current_thread_messages.any? %>
```

This delete selected link won't be part of the loop because I don't want it showing for every message but at the top of the thread instead.

1. I need to figure out how to pass the array with all the selected messages ideas into that argument. How do I get them from the each loop without going into my messages helper and writing some funky method.?
2. I have the checkbox tag e.g. check_box_tag ... how do I setup an empty array and then so I can pass in the messages id? e.g.:

   <%= check_box_tag ......., :value => message.id &>

Help would be appreciated. I looked at an old screencast in railscasts but it's from 2007 I think.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can make `name="message_ids[]"` for multi select inputs. It will get passed as an array through HTTP server to your `params[:message_ids]`.
2. From the HTML side of the problem, I think that form helper `<%= check_box_tag "message_ids[]", :value => message.id %>` should suffice.
3. In the controller action, log the `params[:message_ids]` and look it up, it should be an Array.

Comment: But each loop is belpw the link for delete selected. How will that checkbox work with the delete all link when clicked?

Comment: Doesn't work with link_to as it can't pick up the form. So I'd have to use a submit_tag and put the each loop insite the actual form.

Comment: Yes, you have to do a full form with a submit_tag

Comment: It seems to now show params when I use the submit_tag now to update_all what would I type? I've tested updating each in console and that works. I basically do m = Message.find(pass in array). Then m.each do |msg| then msg.update_attribute('sender_status', 1) think works fine but i'm guessing it's slowing than just updating all at once using update_all

Comment: Ids are passed to request parameters, so it should be: `Message.find(params[:message_ids]).update_all key: value`. Yes, `#update_all` makes only one query to the database, whereas looping through `n` messages would make `n` queries.

Comment: i get undefined method `update_all' for #<Array:0x000001036d70c8>

Comment: Right, sorry about that, the thing here is that `#update_all` must be run on Relation object and `#find` gets array of results. The proper way here should be: `Message.where("id IN (?)", params[:message_ids]).update_all key: value`

Comment: Message.update_all(['recipient_status = ?', 1], :id => params[:message_ids]) That worked for me but in order to update the correct users message status column I add an if statement to the end with my other message delete options. How ever for this delete selected feature I can't add a statement such as if message.sender_id == current_user.id or if message.recipient_id == current_user.id. These conditions make sure the correct sender_status columns are updated.

Comment: Then I have something like this at the end incase both statuses are set to 1. message.destroy if message.sender_status == 1 && message.recipient_status == 1

Comment: Please read [query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) on ruby guides. To do all of the above in one query, with validation of your columns, do this: `Message.where("id IN (?)", params[:message_ids]).where(sender_id: current_user.id).update_all("recipient_status = 1")` and for the other query of yours (if I understand correctly): `Message.where("id IN (?)", params[:message_ids]).where(sender_status: 1, recipient_status: 1).destroy_all`. If this doesn't make sense to you, please read the link above. Proper use of queries will save your app database requests.